# algoritmo esta atropelando a regra que estabeleci

Tags: algoritmo, lógica, operadores, visualg

Gostaria de perguntar sobre uma questão que não esta entrando na minha cabeça.

Segue a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo eu definindo que para que seja escrito "O triangulo e isósceles" as 3 condições tenham que ser FALSAS, a informação continua "invadindo" outras estruturas condicionais e imprimindo o valor na tela, mesmo com uma condição sendo VERDADEIRA.

O problema pode ser resolvido com o uso do operador Logico "ou". Mas o que eu queria entender realmente, o porque o meu algoritmo esta atropelando a regra que estabeleci.

```
 algoritmo "oi"    //VISUALG - PORTUGOL

var

   L1, L2, L3: real
   
   EQ, ES, tri: logico

inicio
               escreva ("Digite o primeiro lado: ")
               leia (L1)

               escreva ("Digite o segundo lado: ")
               leia (L2)

               escreva ("Digite o terceiro lado: ")
               leia (L3)

               EQ <- (L1 = L2) e (L2 = L3) //triangulo equilatero

               ES <- (L1<>L2) e (L1<>L3) e (L2<>L3) // triangulo escaleno

               tri <- (l1 > l2+l3) ou (l2 > l1+l3) ou (l3 > l2+l1)// verifica se e um triangulo

               se (tri = verdadeiro) entao

                     escreva ("Triangulo inavalido")
                     
               fimse
            
               se (EQ = VERDADEIRO) entao

                     escreval ("O triangulo e equilatero. ")

               fimse

               se   (ES = VERDADEIRO) entao

                    escreval ("O triangulo e escaleno. ")

               fimse
                
               se (ES e EQ e tri = FALSO) entao

                    escreval ("O triangulo e isoceles.")
                
               fimse


           


fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    se (EQ = VERDADEIRO) entao

            escreval ("O triangulo e equilatero. ")

            fimse

            se   (ES = VERDADEIRO) entao

            escreval ("O triangulo e escaleno. ")
            fimse
            
            se (ES ou EQ ou tri = FALSO) entao
            
            escreval ("O triangulo e isoceles.")
            
            fimse
```

Não conheço essa linguagem, mas acredito que seja essa parte do código.

Praticamente você faz a condição (Ele é "A" ou "B")

Depois você manda pra ele que, se não for "A" ou "B" ele é "C", por isso que está acontecendo isso

**EDIT:** O ideal nesse caso seria fazer um switch, você conseguiria fazer as condições e não teria esse problema (como eu disse, não conheço essa linguagem então não sei se tem switch ou como seria chamado)

**EDIT2:** Também pode colocar

```
se (ES e EQ = FALSO) entao //Aqui seria a condição para ver que ele é isósceles
...
```

Answer (score 0):

O operador lógico "e" só resultará em VERDADEIRO se todos os valores(verdadeiro ou falso) forem VERDADEIROS. Ou seja, no caso da imagem, onde EQ = VERDADEIRO, ES = FALSO E TRI = FALSO, o resultado será FALSO e por isso o escreval será executado.

```
se (ES e EQ e tri = FALSO) entao
   escreval ("O triangulo e isoceles.")
fimse
```

Além disso, a variável tri, da forma que está em seu código, verifica se NÃO é um triângulo. Ou seja, se os valores do lado forem de um triangulo válido o resultado de TRI será FALSO.

```
tri <- (l1 > l2+l3) ou (l2 > l1+l3) ou (l3 > l2+l1)
```

A forma de resultar em VERDADEIRO caso lados de um triângulo válido seria:

```
tri <- (l1 < l2 + l3) e (l2 < l1 + l3) e ( l3 < l1 + l2)
```